# rs.last() gives Invalid operation for forward only resultset : last

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to get the row count of a result set by:

```
rs.last();
int row_count = rs.getRow();
```

but im getting an `Invalid operation for forward only resultset : last` error.  The result set is getting its data from an Oracle 10g database.

Here is how i set up my connection:

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + oracle_ip_address + ":" + oracle_db_port + ":" + oracle_db_sid;
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, oracle_db_username, oracle_db_password);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`ResultSet.last()` and other "absolutely-indexed" query operations are only available when the result set is *scrollable*; otherwise, you can only iterate one-by-one through the *forward-only* result set.

The following example (from [the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)) demonstrates how to create a scrollable `ResultSet`.

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b FROM TABLE2");
```

Keep in mind that there are performance implications to using scrollable queries.  If the goal of this particular `ResultSet` is only to grab its last value, please consider refining your query to return only that result.

Comment: As per latest specification, we have to add two parameters to the createStatement() - `Statement statement = con.createStatement(resultSetType, resultSetConcurrency);` as described by cheeken, we have to pass `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` but with that we also have to pass one more parameter - please refer this - `resultSetType a result set type; one of ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, or ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE
resultSetConcurrency a concurrency type; one of ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY or ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`

Comment: Please help me it's saying `The method createStatement() in the type Connection is not applicable for the arguments (int)` when I try to execute `Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
);
`

Comment: @StringForever refer to what PareshKumar has mentioned.

Comment: @danielad Actually, that method signature has always required two parameters. The code in the original was always incorrect. I have now corrected it (and updated the broken link).

Answer (score 5):

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement ("SELECT * FROM
         EMPLOYEE_TABLE WHERE LASTNAME = ?" ,
         ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE , 
         ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE ,
         ResultSet.HOLD_CURSOR_OVER_COMMIT) ;
```

For prepared statements, you must specify, at a minimum, both the type *and* the concurrency mode for `last()` and `isLast()` to work.

Comment: isLast() does not require the cursor to be scrollable. last() requires it.

Comment: @isaac.hazan, not true for any driver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597068/islast-method-for-a-type-forward-only-result-set

Comment: ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE is NOT recommended to be used in commercial projects. Please avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```java
String rowCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) as numberOfRows FROM (SELECT * FROM names)";
Statement stat = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(rowCount);
int lastRow = rs.getInt("numberOfRows");
System.out.println(lastRow);
```

Instead of `SELECT * FROM names` use your query.