# isLast() method for a TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY result set

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have been trying to search for a way in which I would know if I am on the last row of my result set and I found the isLast() method.

I did something like:

```
if(rs.isLast()) {
    //do some operation here
}
```

But it game me an error: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.

I searched for a solution and it said that I should change the TYPE_FORDWARD_ONLY. But right now, I was wondering if there is a way for me to know if I am in the last record set by using the TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a method[`isAfterLast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isAfterLast%28%29) which you can check after a call to `next`. This is also not required to be supported for TYPE_FORDWARD_ONLY, but you might try it anyway.

Comment: Same exception for Oracle driver (ojdbc8)

Answer (score 0):

Your connector probably doesn't support `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` you can check it using [DatabaseMetaData#supportsResultSetType(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#supportsResultSetType%28int%29).

Comment: All JDBC drivers are required at minimum to support TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY resultsets (section 6.3 JDBC 4.1 spec). The methods like `afterLast`, `isLast` etc are not required to be implemented for TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, and are - in general - not really useful for TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY resultsets (which is why they are not required to be implemented).

Answer (score 0):

If your driver does not support `afterLast` and `isLast` and you can only use TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY resultsets, then you will need to process all rows, and then do the extra thing you want to do with the last row after you have read all rows.