# resultset.last() throws an exception in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I'm trying to count the number of rows that returns a function on  oracle BBDD. I've seen in some other questions (for instance: [rs.last() gives Invalid operation for forward only resultset : last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007051/rs-last-gives-invalid-operation-for-forward-only-resultset-last)), that needs to be added *ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY* to *callablestatement*.

I've tried *ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE* , also *ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE*... without result. I still get the same invalid operation exception.

What I'm missing?

Heres my code:

```
String call = "{ ? = call MyProcedure (?) }"; 
CallableStatement cstmt= conn.prepareCall(call, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
cstmt.setString(2,"param 1");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

cstmt.execute();
ResultSet rset = (ResultSet)cstmt.getObject(1);
rset.last(); //Exception comes here
int rowsnumber = rset.getRow();
```

Thanks.

Edit:

As said in the comments, I add first the Oracle function I'm calling:

```
create or replace FUNCTION MyProcedure
( IdC IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
  c_result sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_result FOR SELECT name, properties FROM city WHERE name = IdC;
  RETURN c_result;
END;
```

And the Stack Trace:

```
Stack: java.sql.SQLException: Operación no válida para el juego de resultados de sólo reenvío : last
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.last(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:646)
    at MyPackage.CoreWS.ExProcedure(CoreWS.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:120)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:229)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:667)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:286)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:295)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:128)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3679)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1686)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1646)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace

Comment: Try this one? [Go to last row from result set in jdbc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659083/go-to-last-row-from-result-set-in-jdbc-with-sql-server)

Comment: Is it really Invalid Operation or SQLFeatureNotSupportedException

Comment: Have you checked if the result set is actually scrollable? Because the result set type as configured only has an effect if the stored procedure itself produces a result set, and even then a JDBC driver can (and sometimes will) downgrade the type if it can't satisfy the request. In this case you are getting an output parameter that **is** a result set, that is not the same as having a procedure that produces a result set.

Comment: Using afterLast isn't working too. @Jens stack added, added too the oracle function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to move its cursor only forward is the default behavior for a ResultSet and is the only cursor movement possible with drivers that implement only the **JDBC 1.0 API**. This kind of result set has the type ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY and is referred to as a forward only result set.

If a driver implements the cursor movement methods in the **JDBC 2.0 core API**, its result sets can be scrollable. A scrollable result set's cursor can move both forward and backward as well as to a particular row. The following methods move the cursor backward, to the first row, to the last row, to a particular row number, to a specified number of rows from the current row, and so on: previous, first, last, absolute, relative, afterLast, and beforeFirst.

Can you please confirm the version of your API ??

Reference: [Result set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/resultset.html)

Also as suggested by Mark Rotteveel in comments, why don't you make the cursor as an outparameter and fetch it explicitly instead of using RETURN in the function and verify if it is working?